# xinitrc.d content are not applied when running startx

Tags: linux, xserver

I have a script which allows me to restart my running Xserver. However, whenever the Xserver run back again, all the contents of xinitrc.d folder aren't applied.

```
rm /tmp/startx.logs
LOOPTC=0
while [ $LOOPTC -eq 0 ]
do
   pidof TerminalConfig 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
   LOOPTC=$?
   sleep 1
   echo Tc not closed >> /tmp/startx.logs
done
killall gdm 2>/dev/null &
pkill x
if grep ^AUTOLOGIN /etc/sysconfig/autologin | egrep "NO|no|No|nO" ; then
   echo autologin off >> /tmp/startx.logs
   LOOPX=0
   while [ $LOOPX -eq 0 ]
   do
      pidof X 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
      LOOPX=$?
      sleep 1
      echo X not closed >> /tmp/startx.logs
   done
fi
clear >> /dev/tty1
for (( i=0; i<4; i++ )) ; do
  sleep 1
  echo Please wait while restarting X11 Windows...  >> /dev/tty1
done
clear >> /dev/tty1
ps ax | grep startx > /tmp/startx.result
sed -e s/.*grep.*//g -e /^$/d /tmp/startx.result -i
echo $(date) :startx: >> /tmp/startx.logs
cat /tmp/startx.result >> /tmp/startx.logs
if [ -s /tmp/startx.result ] ; then
  echo Thu Feb  1 22:50:08 UTC 2018 :startx already running, no need to     execute startx >> /tmp/startx.logs
else
  killall gdm 2>/dev/null &
  startx
  echo $(date) :startx not running, executing startx >> /tmp/startx.logs
fi
if grep --quiet if [ ! /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc; then
  cp -f /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.old /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
rm -f /tmp/startx.result
#rm -f /tmp/restart-x.sh
```

Note that this script is always run on the Xserver. All the xinitrc.d contents are always applied whenever I run startx from the console (without Xserver running).

I'm wondering, why aren't the xinitrc.d files applied even if I have already ensured that the contents of the xinitrc.d folder should be applied using a for-loop and placed it in the xinitrc file?

Comment: You might find a more knowledgeable audience over at [unix.se].  It seems to be more about the X server's operation than about programming, which could make it off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight. I'll try your suggestion